# PostGIS query to select number of points per polygon and year

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, point-in-polygon, optimization

I have two tables in a PostGIS database:

**`rides`**, containing about 3 million datasets:

- `ride_uid` *(unique integer)*
- `start_geom` *(point geometry with index in 4326)*
- `end_geom` *(point geometry with index in 4326)*
- `start_date_year` *(integer)*
- `end_date_year` *(integer)*
- a lot more stuff

This `rides` table also has some invalid geometries in it, namely `NULL` values in `start_geom` or `end_geom` or non-valid geometries laying somewhere near north pole or sahara dessert. So I'd check for that using `where ST_Within(st.start_geom,ST_MakeEnvelope(5, 35, 20, 55, 4326))` to prevent a reprojection error.

**`polygons`**, containing about 30 datasets:

- `uid_key` *(string)*
- `name` *(string)*
- `geometry` *(multipolygons with index in 25832)*
- a lot more stuff

**I want to figure out the start's and end's for all polygon's and a given range of years.** I also want to consider 0 rides in a year/polygon. E.g. as result:

| PolygonUID | Year | N_Starts | N_Ends |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2015 | 55 | 33 |
| A | 2016 | 0 | 22 |
| A | 2017 | 1001 | 0 |
| B | 2015 | 63 | 12 |
| B | 2016 | 10 | 666 |
| B | 2017 | 0 | 0 |

I am struggling to find an efficient query to achieve my goal in one go. This is what I got so far; It returns my desired result for only starts or only ends in about ~4-5 minutes (which is acceptable).

```sql
select
hlpr.uid_key,
hlpr.name,
hlpr.y,
coalesce(count(s.ride_uid),0) as cnt_start --,
--coalesce(count(e.ride_uid),0) as cnt_end -- takes forever with this at the same time
from
(
    select
    poly.uid_key,
    poly.name,
    cal.y,
    poly.geom
    from schema_b.polygons as poly
    cross join
        (
            select cast(generate_series(2015,2021) as integer) as y
        ) as cal
) as hlpr

left join
(
    select
    st.ride_uid,
    st.start_date_year,
    st.start_geom,
    pol.uid_key
    from schema_a.rides as st
    left join
    (
        select
        uid_key,
        geom
        from schema_b.polygons
    ) as pol
    on ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(st.start_geom,25832),pol.geom)
    where ST_Within(st.start_geom,ST_MakeEnvelope(5, 35, 20, 55, 4326))
) as s
on s.start_date_year = hlpr.y and s.uid_key = hlpr.uid_key

-- takes forever with this:
/*
left join
(
    select
    en.ride_uid,
    en.end_date_year,
    en.end_geom,
    pol.uid_key
    from schema_a.rides as en
    left join
    (
        select
        uid_key,
        geom
        from schema_b.polygons
    ) as pol
    on ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(en.end_geom,25832),pol.geom)
    where ST_Within(en.end_geom,ST_MakeEnvelope(5, 35, 20, 55, 4326))
) as e
on e.end_date_year = hlpr.y and e.uid_key = hlpr.uid_key
*/

group by
hlpr.uid_key,
hlpr.name,
hlpr.y

order by
hlpr.uid_key,
hlpr.y
```

**Can I optimize this query somehow to get my desired result faster in one go?** Or is this an unusual approach that should be avoided at all and instead only one count be done per query and the results merged manually afterwards?

Comment: Reworded for understand and clarity: For each polygon in `polygons` and for every year in a set of years you want the number of rows in `rides` that have their `start_geom` or `end_geom` geom inside the polygon per year (for `start_geom` it must match `start_date_year`, for `end_geom` it must match `end_date_year`), correct?

Comment: Typical starters: Do you have indexes on `ST_Transform(start_geom,25832)`, `start_date_year`, `uid_key`, `name`? What does `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` say (https://explain.depesz.com/)?

Comment: @bugmenot123 yes, that is correct. I only have indexes on the original geometries. `explain analyze` runs forever, `explain` says: https://explain.depesz.com/s/L1lN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than a series of *set-wise* `JOIN`s (that necessarily creates extremely inefficient *cartesian products*), use a ***correlated expression*** during a traversal of your `polygons` table - that way you can fully benefit from indexes on both `rides.start_geom` & `rides.end_geom`.

If possible, I favor a `LATERAL` expression:

```
SELECT  ply.uid_key AS "PolygonUID",
        _y AS "Year",
        st._cnt AS "N_Starts",
        et._cnt AS "N_Ends"
FROM    polygons AS ply
CROSS JOIN
        GENERATE_SERIES(2015, 2021) AS _y
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS _cnt
    FROM   rides AS t
    WHERE  ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(ply.geom, 4326), t.start_geom)
      AND  t.start_date_year = _y
) AS st
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS _cnt
    FROM   rides AS t
    WHERE  ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(ply.geom, 4326), t.end_geom)
      AND  t.end_date_year = _y
) AS et
;
```

*Here in full verbose mode - all `CROSS JOIN`s can literally be replaced by a `,`.*

For each row in `polygons`

- we create a *cross product* with the desired range of years (`GENERATE_SERIES`), virtually increasing row count in the set
- from which we then take the initial rows `polygon.geom` and the cross joined year `_y`, and pass those to both `LATERAL` queries
- which, in turn, will run a highly performant `COUNT` on the `rides` table each, utilizing its spatial indexes

Note that the key here is to pass each traversed `polygon.geom` into the indexes on `rides` - meaning that you need to transform `polygon.geom` to match the SRID of both `rides` geometries. Not being able to utilize the spatial indexes due to the transformation is a major issue in your query. This way there is now no need to run a pre-filter by envelope.

---

This is effectively equivalent to using an actual *correlated sub-query* per value set (*start* & *end*) per row:

```
SELECT  ply.uid_key AS "PolygonUID",
        _y AS "Year",
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*) AS _cnt
          FROM   rides AS t
          WHERE  ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(ply.geom, 4326), t.start_geom)
            AND  t.start_date_year = y
        ) AS "N_Starts",
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*) AS _cnt
          FROM   rides AS t
          WHERE  ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(ply.geom, 4326), t.end_geom)
            AND  t.end_date_year = y
        ) AS "N_Ends"
FROM    regions AS ply
CROSS JOIN
        GENERATE_SERIES(2015, 2021) AS _y
;
```

but these two concepts *may* use fundamentally different query plans, with different benefits based on use case. Here, this latter query *should* be slightly slower.

Comment: Note that, while query syntax increases somewhat, `ST_Dump`ing (and potentially even `ST_SubDivide`ing) your *MultiPolygon*s into a fully indexed table will have a significant impact on query time. With 30 simple polygons (30 vertices each), covering roughly 30% of the points layer extent, the `LATERAL` query returns ~ 1.5 million hits (summed over `_cnt`) from ~40M points in 20 seconds.

Comment: @MrXsquared likely an index issue - your query vs mine on the data set I outlined is 3 minutes vs. 20 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

So I did some *logical thinking*: If one counting-subquery (`hlpr`) takes ~4-5 minutes, I could just do the second counting in another nested subquery (`hlprb`) within the first sub-query (`hlpr`) and join them together, then it should take twice as long as for 1 sub-query: ~9 minutes. And so it is: you can just do **further nesting** on the second counting like:

```sql
select
hlprb.uid_key,
hlprb.name,
hlprb.y,
hlprb.cnt_start,
coalesce(count(e.ride_uid),0) as cnt_end

from
(
    select
    hlpr.uid_key,
    hlpr.name,
    hlpr.y,
    coalesce(count(s.ride_uid),0) as cnt_start
    from
    (
        select
        poly.uid_key,
        poly.name,
        cal.y,
        poly.geom
        from schema_b.polygons as poly
        cross join
            (
                select cast(generate_series(2018,2021) as integer) as y
            ) as cal
    ) as hlpr

    left join
    (
        select
        st.ride_uid,
        st.start_date_year,
        st.start_geom,
        pol.uid_key
        from schema_a.rides as st
        left join
        (
            select
            uid_key,
            geom
            from schema_b.polygons
        ) as pol
        on ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(st.start_geom,25832),pol.geom)
        where ST_Within(st.start_geom,ST_MakeEnvelope(5, 35, 20, 55, 4326))
    ) as s
    on s.start_date_year = hlpr.y and s.uid_key = hlpr.uid_key
    
    group by
    hlpr.uid_key,
    hlpr.name,
    hlpr.y
) as hlprb

left join
(
    select
    en.ride_uid,
    en.end_date_year,
    en.end_geom,
    pol.uid_key
    from schema_a.rides as en
    left join
    (
        select
        uid_key,
        geom
        from schema_b.polygons
    ) as pol
    on ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(en.end_geom,25832),pol.geom)
    where ST_Within(en.end_geom,ST_MakeEnvelope(5, 35, 20, 55, 4326))
) as e
on e.end_date_year = hlprb.y and e.uid_key = hlprb.uid_key

group by
hlprb.uid_key,
hlprb.name,
hlprb.y,
hlprb.cnt_start

order by
hlprb.uid_key,
hlprb.y
```